# Certificate Pinning on UWP

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp, certificate-pinning

We have a `Xamarin.Forms` project that is currently compiled for `Android`, `iOS` and `UWP` using .NET Standard 2.0 for the shared project.

The communications is performed through a `WCF` Service Contract.

In order to pin the certificate we implemented the following code as per examples. This works correctly on `Android` and `iOS` after making sure that are using the necessary `HttpClient` implementations under their project properties.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ValidateServerCertificate;

private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender,
                                       X509Certificate certificate,
                                       X509Chain chain,
                                       SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    // Make sure we have a certificate to check.
    if (certificate == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (sslPolicyErrors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return this.KnownKeys.Contains(certificate.GetCertHashString(), 
                                   StringComparer.Ordinal);
}
```

`UWP` however is proving to be rather stubborn. I am unable to get the callback to fire at any stage of the communications.

I have also looked in to implementing our own `X509CertificateValidator` and supplying it to the `WCF` config however that also does nothing.

**Questions**

1. Do I need to/Am I able to specify a `HttpClient` implementation under `UWP` much like you can for `Android` and `iOS` that will fix this?
2. Is there another approach that I am currently missing?

Comment: Rather than `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`, how about use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`'s `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`?

Comment: @HappyNomad do you mean `HttpClientHandler`s `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback`. If so I am pretty sure we did try that but it had no effect.

Comment: @HappyNomad thanks though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use the [HttpBaseProtocolFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter) Class in the [Windows.Web.Http Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http) in you UWP app. With the [HttpBaseProtocolFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter) instance, you can subscribe [HttpBaseProtocolFilter.ServerCustomValidationRequested](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.filters.httpbaseprotocolfilter.servercustomvalidationrequested) event. In this event handler, you can perform extra validation (in addition to the OS default) of the server SSL certificate.

Comment: Thank you although if I am correct and things haven't moved on from these posts: [msdn](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/4dac8454-64c0-41f7-98b5-bddf184f7703/uwpignore-ssl-certificate-errors-when-using-wcf-in-uwp) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150428/windows-10-universal-wcf-generated-client-setting-to-ignore-ssl-certificate-erro) then I am not able to achieve what I need using the generated WCF Service Contract code and would have to go direct using an `HttpClient`?

Comment: There is a [blog](http://blog.infernored.com/securing-communications-via-certificate-pinning-in-uwp) where it includes the detailed code to implement certificate pinning using the `HttpClient`, you can have a try.

Comment: Yes thank you! While the answer doesn't quite cover what I needed the blog post mentioned in your comment does.